# show error during registration in typo3

Tags: typo3

For providing registration option in typo3 website I insatll sr_feuser_register_3.0.1 extension. In addition to this extension I install static info table & div 2007 extension.

I included registration form in a page by including sr_feuser template css in typoscript template and also insert plugin. But when I register myself in registration form it shows error:-

"You must enter the same password twice.
The password must contain at most 40 characters.
Please enter a password!"

Password is entered correctly but it shows this problem again & again & I am not able to register because of this problem. Please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the problem. Problem is that when I put registration form & login form in same page then it starts showing problem. But if I put only registration form then it starts working.

But I have to put both forms in one page. Please tell me how can I do that.